# How do I deactive the suggestion box in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I come from Visual C++ Version 1.52 and like to see my code when I'm typing. I uninstalled IntelliSense and a suggestion box still comes up, covering most of my code. Can anyone tell me how to turn it off permanently? Thank you.

Comment: "I uninstalled IntelliSense" - that's not possible

Comment: Tools > Text Editor > C/C++ > General > Uncheck "Auto list members" etc.